# How to get random from coordinates

Tags: java

I'm trying to get a random number within a range/maximum (e.g. 0-50, 0-100) based on coordinates supplied. This is used on an image where it should remain consistent on refresh, but the 'pattern' should be random.

This function is meant to be called when drawing the picture.

```
function hash(x, y, max) {
  return Math.random(x+y) * max;
}
hash(210, 239, 100);
```

Comment: Please try: `Math.floor(Math.random() * 51);` --> it should return a random number between 0 & 50 (both 0 & 50 inclusive). If you need the random number to remain consistent based on values of x, y, len - you may try to memoize the random-number generation.

Comment: What do you mean by random pattern? Do you want no co-relation between supplied values and the returned hashId?

Comment: @user29414082909, Alright, Apologies in advance but you are trying to plot a 2D map but you are reducing co-ordinates to return one value only. Isn't it the incorrect way to do this? If there is a co-relation you will end up getting a line and if there isn't you will end up getting a scattered graph but it won't be any meaningful representation of the data you have.

Comment: @user29414082909, Gotcha! one more thing, Are you passing "len" to get the answer in the range "0-len"?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function .. just pass the max number and it will generate a random number whenever it's called

```js
function getRandomNumber(max) {
 return Math.ceil(Math.random()*max);
}

console.log(getRandomNumber(50));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Math.random()` to generate random values in range. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

**Getting a random number between two values**

```js
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

console.log(getRandomArbitrary(210, 239));
```

**Getting a random integer between two values**

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}

console.log(getRandomInt(210, 239));
```

**Getting a random integer between two values, inclusive**

```js
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min); //The maximum is inclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}

console.log(getRandomIntInclusive(210, 239));
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to get consistent value, based on the input params.
But this value should not be linearly co-related else you will end up getting stripes of some color. So, we are gonna take modulo of x and y co-ordinated to randomize the process and escape linear co-relation. Then, we will try to fit values in a particular range. See my approach below:

```js
function getHashId(x, y, max) {
    const code = ((x % 13) + (y % 17)) //you can use any prime number
    return code % max; //Make sure it's in range 0-max
}

console.log(getHashId(210, 239, 100));
```